# Best practice for storing object in multiple containers

Tags: c++

I want to store an object in both a `priority_queue` but also in an `unordered_map`. Is there a best practice for doing something like this? I've considered storing the objects in a separate container (say `array`), and then relinquishing the pointers to the other two containers.

I'm hesitant to do this though, because that would mean I would have to write some additional comparitors to handle the fact that the containers would be storing pointers, rather than actual objects. In addition there is addition work managing ownership of the objects I'd like to not have to deal with.

So, I'm wondering if there isn't already an established best way to do this?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<T>` guarantees proper ownership sharing if this is your main concern

Comment: I agree: is it sufficient to have the ownership through a smart pointer?

Comment: That might work actually, lemme try it out...

Comment: Is it not practical to store copies?

Comment: @sircodesalot: please bare in mind one thing: if the objects are accessible from outside of `std::priority_queue` then there is a threat that the value based on which the objects have been ordered by queue can be changed, and priority_queue does no longer work as expected

Comment: @Piotr, the priority of the objects is immutable. Basically, I'm writing a register allocator for a set of variables. The variables cannot change their priority. But registers need to spill over based on the priority of their contents.

Comment: If I use a `shared_ptr` does that mean I still need to write my own comparators for `priority_queue` and `unordered_map`, or is there a standard comparator for pointers?

Comment: Take a look at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). This allows specifying a single container type that can be accessed in both ordered and unordered fashion.

Comment: @sircodesalot: you need to write your own comparator taking pointers and comparing the dereferenced values. However, it is still better to use (smart)pointers rather than raw objects, because `std::priority_queue<T>` uses (most probably) `std::deque<T>` as a wrapped container, which copies (or std::move's) elements when they must be reordered.

Comment: @sircodesalot (I'm going to get some hate for this one) If these structures are both internal and never exposed, I'd actually argue away from using a shared pointer. Have one of the containers have explicit ownership, and have the other use references. The only (real) reason to use a shared pointer is when the ownership of the object could be confused/can't be clearly defined.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams that pretty much spells out my dillema right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've seen that you have to store a reference (of some sort) to the object if you want 1 thing to appear in 2 places. Whilst you once would have used a pointer, today we have [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

This wraps the pointer so you don't have to manage lifetime ownership- the pointer will only get delete'd when the reference count of the shared_ptr drops to 0, ie when everyone holding the shared_ptr has relinquished it. You use the shared_ptr object as a real object so it's easy to manage in your containers.

If you don't have a C++11 compiler, you can use the [boost version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) (that comes with an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/example/shared_ptr_example.cpp) of storing shared_ptr objects in both a vector and a set)

Comment: Using C++11 (ideally without boost).

Comment: all that happened is the shared_ptr that was in boost migrated to the standard library in C++11. Apart from the namespace they're pretty much the same.

Comment: Example is helpful, Thanks!

Comment: "Whilst you once would have used a pointer, today we have shared_ptr.". This thinking is much too extreme. There is absolutely nothing wrong with raw pointers if used correctly in the right circumstances. `shared_ptr` solves a number of lifetime issues, but applied blindly can cause trouble and overly complicated program architectures as well.